# Make Spacy tokenizer not split on /

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

How do I modify the English tokenizer to prevent splitting tokens on the `'/'` character?

For example, the following string should be one token:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
doc = nlp("12/AB/568793")

for t in doc:
    print(f"[{t.pos_} {t.text}]")

# produces
#[NUM 12]
#[SYM /]
#[ADJ AB/568793]
```

Comment: what is `nlp` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach is a variation on removing a rule in the ["Modifying existing rule sets"](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizer-additions) from Spacy documentation:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
infixes = nlp.Defaults.infixes
assert(len([x for x in infixes if '/' in x])==1)  # there seems to just be one rule that splits on /'s
# remove that rule; then modify the tokenizer
infixes = [x for x in infixes if '/' not in x]
nlp.tokenizer.infix_finditer = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(infixes).finditer
```

Comment: This answer is a good starting point but technically not correct, because that rule containing '/' in fact also concerns other characters, including '=','<','>' etc.  Simply deleting it will break the rules for others.   So, I would suggest modifying instead of deleting. Due to the limit in Comment, I open another answer for the detailed code.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Dave is a good starting point, but the correct way I think is to modify instead of deleting the rule.

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
infixes = nlp.Defaults.infixes
rule_slash = [x for x in infixes if '/' in x][0]
print(rule_slash)  # check the rule
```

You will see the rule also concerns other characters, including '=','<','>' etc.

We only remove '/' from the rule:

```
rule_slash_new = rule_slash.replace('/', '')
# replace the old rule with the new rule
infixes = [r if r!=rule_slash else rule_slash_new for r in infixes]
nlp.tokenizer.infix_finditer = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(infixes).finditer
```

This way the tokenizer will still split correctly in the cases of "A=B" or "A>B" etc.